# boost intrusive get next directly from node

Tags: c++, boost, boost-intrusive

Is it possible to get next node/element directly from node/element? Like so:

```
struct Data{
   boost::intrusive::list_member_hook<> node;

   Data* get_next(){
       node.get_next() ???
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many boost intrusive containers have a static member function [`s_iterator_to`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/intrusive/obtaining_iterators_from_values.html) to get an iterator directly from a value.

Thus you can get an iterator then use the iterator interface:

```
struct Data{
   boost::intrusive::list_member_hook<> node;

   inline Data* get_next();
}

namespace bis = boost::intrusive;

using List = bis::list<Data,
        bis::member_hook<Data, bis::list_member_hook<>, &Data::node>
      >;

Data* Data::get_next() {
    return &*++List::s_iterator_to(*this);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NxwoFBkncQediY6c)

Comment: What about terminal nodes? `get_next()` should return `null_ptr` if there is no next node.

Comment: @tower120 It's impossible. Intrusive list uses a head node as sentinel. An entry node doesn't have enough info in itself to determine whether it's a terminal. nodes are not null-terminated.